# Python 3.6 disable SSL (verify=False) does not work

Tags: python, ssl

iam using Python 3.6 on my Linux machine. And my HTTPS requests does not work.

```
import requests

requests.get('https://192.168.56.101:4665/v1/objects/services/docker-icinga2!random-005', verify=False, auth=('root', 'icinga'))
```

The response is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

With the disable_warnings
so that code:

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Disable flag warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

requests.get('https://192.168.56.101:4665/v1/objects/services/docker-     
icinga2!random-005', auth=('root', 'icinga'))
```

I get this as response (u see in the picture) 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNpxS.png)

Answer (score 3):

To disable this warning, you can use requests.package.disable_warnings

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Disable flag warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

requests.get('https://192.168.56.101:4665/v1/objects/services/docker-icinga2!random-005', verify=False, auth=('root', 'icinga'))
```

Comment: If i copy your code. It give me at first the response to import requests so i write it to the top and then that:
(Its to long for this comment) I get a Traceback fail. 
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
I will write the complete text in the question above.

Comment: Is it on the same requests.get line or an other ?

Comment: What do you mean? The error response or the code in the py script? I added the code an the error response as a picture.

Comment: Sorry, try to keep verify as False